# Prove there's no such algorithm

Tags: logic, algorithms, predicate-logic

> Prove there's no algorithm which gets $\varphi$, a formula without **free-variables** as in input and returns a formula of the form $\varphi ' =\exists x_1,\ldots,\exists x_n \psi$ where $\psi$ is a formula **without quantifiers** such that $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff $\varphi$' is satisfiable.

Note: There's an algorithm for satisfiability of a formula without quantifiers and free variables.

I should get a contradiction with Church thesis somehow.

I'd be glad for help.

Comment: You mean that $\psi$ is without quantifiers?

Comment: Yes, I will rephrase it.